# Cannot connect to isql through ssh'ing to the server

Tags: mysql, sql, ssh, isql

I have a server where isql is been installed. I have to run the query from local server which first do ssh to the server and connect to the db and run the desired query (`SELECT MID, NODE, dateformat(DATETIME,'yymmddhhnnss') as DT FROM EU_TAB WHERE DATETIME='2020-07-01'`). But the db connection itself giving me the below message:

From local prompt I am running below command:

```
]# ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "isql -SWebDB -UMyID -PMyPWD -w2222"
```

But I am getting below message. And its not able to connect.

```
**********************************************
* unixODBC - isql                            *
**********************************************
* Syntax                                     *
*                                            *
*      isql DSN [UID [PWD]] [options]        *
*                                            *
* Options                                    *
*                                            *
* -b         batch.(no prompting etc)        *
* -dx        delimit columns with x          *
* -x0xXX     delimit columns with XX, where  *
*            x is in hex, ie 0x09 is tab     *
* -w         wrap results in an HTML table   *
* -c         column names on first row.      *
*            (only used when -d)             *
* -mn        limit column display width to n *
* -v         verbose.                        *
* -lx        set locale to x                 *
* -q         wrap char fields in dquotes     *
* -3         Use ODBC 3 calls                *
* -n         Use new line processing         *
* -e         Use SQLExecDirect not Prepare   *
* -k         Use SQLDriverConnect            *
* --version  version                         *
*                                            *
* Commands                                   *
*                                            *
* help - list tables                         *
* help table - list columns in table         *
* help help - list all help options          * 
*                                            *
* Examples                                   *
*                                            *
*      isql WebDB MyID MyPWD -w < My.sql     *
*                                            *
*      Each line in My.sql must contain      *
*      exactly 1 SQL command except for the  *
*      last line which must be blank (unless *
*      -n option specified).                 *
*                                            *
* Please visit;                              *
*                                            *
*      http://www.unixodbc.org               *
*      nick@lurcher.org                      *
*      pharvey@codebydesign.com              *
**********************************************
```

Is it something I am doing wrong here?

I wanted to run this query in local prompt something like this:

```
]# ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "isql -SWebDB -UMyID -PMyPWD -w2222 <<EOT SELECT MID, NODE, dateformat(DATETIME,'yymmddhhnnss') as DT FROM EU_TAB WHERE DATETIME='2020-07-01' go EOT"
```

Here it should give the result as per the query. But I am unable to move forward because of the above message. Please correct me if its the write format to mention the query in `EOT`.

Answer (score 0):

`isql` is showing you a usage diagram because you're calling it incorrectly.  According to what it's displaying, the `-S`, `-U`, and `-P` options you're attempting to use don't exist (possibly you're used to a different version of `isql`?), and you would want to run:

```
]# ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "isql WebDB MyID MyPWD -w2222"
```